# Django/Eclipse Integration

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I've downloaded django onto my system and tried importing it into eclipse.
Eclipse keeps telling me after i direct it to the python interpreter that django is not there, which it most certainly is, felling this could be a quick fix, but thats how i've installed every other program.

Answer (score 0):

PyDev will statically resolve your interpreter's site-specific paths once you configure it. It means you'll have to reconfigure your interpreter every time your site's paths change, like installing a new package such as Django.

Here's what the [Interpreter Configuration](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) documentation says:

> ## What if I add something new in my System PYTHONPATH after configuring [the interpreter]?
>
> If you add something to your python installation, you need to either
> add it manually as a 'new folder' in the System PYTHONPATH (if it's
> still not under a folder in the PYTHONPATH) or (recommended) remove
> your interpreter and add it again, then, press apply.

Comment: yeah, so basically how can i  get python interpreter to recognise django

Comment: _Either manually add it as a "new folder" in the System PYTHONPATH or remove the interpreter and add it again._