# Loading Django into eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

When i point my django project to my python interpreter 3.2 in the new interpreter window and load files accordingly using the apply button, I hit next it says django is not in the python interpreter , do I need to install django inside the python interpreter??

when i create new project the option of django project is there and i can develop python projects fine, but eclipse won't let me go any further in django sayin django not found....pre requisite is that django is installed into the [ppython/jython/ironpython interpreter.

Any ideas to overcome this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597139/django-eclipse-integration. Please don't ask the same question again @Spencer Hire. You can edit your questions if you want to provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django isn't Python 3 compatible yet. Experimental support is planned in 1.5. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/faq/install/ for more info.